# .next() not working on all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zme2h1uo/1/)***

Above's the jsFiddle of my code.
NOTE: CSS is correct, no fiddling required with that.

As you may be looking at result, there's a plus ( + ) sign in front of some addresses. When you click the topmost cell with plus sign, you see landmark text. But when you click the rest, it doesn't work.
Here's the JQuery I used:

```
$('#landmark').click(function () {     
    $(this).next('#theLandmark').slideToggle();
});
```

Where `#landmark` is the plus (`+`) sign and the rest of the landmark text is `#theLandmark`.
The HTML/CSS/jQuery is working fine, as it works with the first time.
But I feel there's some more code of jQuery missing which can correct it.

Thanks!

Comment: The `id` selector must be **unique** on a website.

Comment: Come on, 4 downvotes? The culprit of the problem is very simple (`id`s not being unique), but I guess that must be pretty discouraging for the asker...question seems OK - we have fiddle and readable description of the issue.

Comment: Good heart, @bardzusny

Comment: @bardzusny, nah I'm not.. Learning all the web-development at once may lead to such flaws, the question may be stupid.. :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is because you have duplicated both the `landmark` and `theLandmark` `id` attributes amongst your elements. `id` must be unique within the page. If you convert them to `class` attributes your code works fine:

```
$('.landmark').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.theLandmark').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<!-- one example instance... -->
<div class='landmark'>+</div>)
<div class='theLandmark hide'><b id='lmText'>Landmark: </b>Dharmkata</div>
```

```css
.landmark {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.theLandmark {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zme2h1uo/3/)

Note that `#lmtext` is also repeated, although that element is not affected by your JS code. You should change that to a class too.